# A "view-only" mode in `screen`?

Tags: gnu-screen, screen-sharing

One of my favorite modes for `screen` is using the `-x` option, wherein multiple users can connect-to the same session (great for team troubleshooting and training purposes).

However, it would be really nice if there were a way to merely watch the session, rather than to be able to accidentally type into it (when you merely want to see what is going on, and not participate (so to speak)).

Is there a way to do this either with `screen` or a similar tool?

I am trying to keep this as low-bandwidth as possible - some users/viewers may be *very* remote, whereupon a VNC connection would be prohibitively slow (also, if it's a headless machine, VNC won't work as it requires an X server, afaik).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per an answer in a [related, but not duplicate, question](https://superuser.com/questions/103820/dump-show-acl-in-gnu-screen), there are access control list controls for multiuser session. This [HOWTO](http://aperiodic.net/screen/multiuser)  discusses options and gives some examples.

Answer (score -1):

if GUI is acceptable, then you can use VNC. There is a viewonly mode there.

Comment: see update to question to clarify